# C++ custom comparator not working MWE

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, comparator, stl-algorithm

I know there has been few posts about this already, so feel free to remove my post, but this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define tol 1e-9
using namespace std;

int n;
vector<pair<double,double>> vec;

struct comparator {
    bool operator () ( pair<double,double> &a, pair<double,double> &b ) {
        if ( fabs(a.first-b.first) < tol )
            return a.second < b.second;
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
};

int main() {
    int i,j,k,ts,cs= 0,m,sz;
    for ( ; 1 == scanf("%d",&n); ) {
        for ( vec.clear(), vec.reserve(n), i = 0; i < n; ++i )
            scanf("%lf %lf",&vec[i].second,&vec[i].first);
        sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),comparator());
        for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
            printf("%lf %lf\n",vec[i].first,vec[i].second);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is not working for this example:

```
2
120 60
60 90
```

I compile this as `g++ -std=c++11 -o a mwe.cpp`, and mine is `g++ version 5.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused `resize()` with `reserve()`.

When you write

```
for ( vec.clear(), vec.reserve(n), i = 0; i < n; ++i )
```

you reserve size `n` for vector `vec`, that is you're instructing `vec` to reserve memory size for a future expansion to `n` elements. But, at the moment, the size of `vec` remain zero.

So, when you write

```
scanf("%lf %lf",&vec[i].second,&vec[i].first);
```

you're writing in uninitialized objects.

Very, very bad.

Technically speaking: you're in UB (Undefined Behavior).

Practically speaking: all can happens.

When you write

```
sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),comparator());
```

you're sorting a vector `vec` of zero size, where `vec.begin()` is equal to `vec.end()`.

In other words: `std::sort()` do absolutely nothing.

Solution: avoid `clear()` (as pointed by Caleth, it's superfluous if you after `resize()` and reset all element) and use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`

```
// -------vvvvvv
for ( vec.resize(n), i = 0; i < n; ++i )
```

Off Topic suggestions:

- avoid not-standard includes as `bits/stdc++.h`
- avoid old C I/O and use the new C++ one; so no `std::scanf()` and `std::printf()` and use `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: @BenVoigt - D'oh! I have to reverse more time to sleep... **reserve** more time to sleep! Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: also the `vec.clear()` is superfluous, it is required to not change the `capacity()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really work on your -in my terms- handwriting. The snippet really looks unreadable. So many statements in the loop initializer. Third loop could use range-based syntax. I Tend to avoid traditional for loops whenever possible.
You can reserve in the begining and keep on with push_back till the assumed capacity is exausted.